# Site does not display content with default encoding

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site "A". I want to change server and domain, so I need to transfer everything from site "A" to site "B".

Allright. I download every file from site "A" and put into `siteB/public_html`. I also set connection settings to the same database as site "A" (of course I changed `localhost` to siteA ip address)

So It looks like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKAHv.png)

The thing is, that when I enter site "A" the defult encoding is set to:
`ISO-8859-2` and everything works properly. (.htaccess contains `AddDefaultCharset iso-8859-2` line)

Unfortunelly, when I enter site "B" the defult encoding is set to: `UTF-8` and I can see that character: � insted of non latin characters.

How it is even possible? Both sites are connected to the same database, both sites contains the same files (databse connection php file is a little bit different in site "B").

Also, what has to be said when i create server with XAMPP and use exactly the same files as site "B" **everything is working properly..**

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the siteB entry file(or other files) encodings didnt get switched to UTF-8 for some reason, using some editor (like sublime text for example)
2. Try to force your encoding like this

```html
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-2">
</head>
```

3. Maybe you forgot to specify the encoding when connecting to your DB. You could post that part of the file here .

Also, are only parts of pages displayed incorrectly, or whole?

Comment: 1. I only edited database connection file (I also checked `ISO-8859-2` encoding in Notepad++)
2.

Comment: 2. Both sites contains `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />` in head. 3. I edited first post. As you can see everything works properly with Xampp. To your last qustion - whole page is wrong formatted.

Comment: If the new server is Apache, maybe it is configured so that you cannot change encodings with htaccess(although that's strange), if not Apache, .htaccess won't work at all. This issue is probably better to forward to your hoster, if you don't have root access to the server filesystem.